# After calling setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) screen is not roating for the second time

Tags: android, android-layout

This question may look similar but it's not the kind of.

I was developing an android app that streams video from the internet and there I had to implement the fullscreen button which toggles screen landscape(full screen) and portrait.

From portrait mode when I need to go to landscape I called the method `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

but next time when I click the button instead of calling the method `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` the screen is not coming in portrait mode back.

**NOTE:** I cant use two separate layouts for portrait and landscape

**UPDATE**

The screen rotation button works this was

```
  mScreenRotateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   void onClick(View v){
        if (inPortrait) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
       } else {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
       }
   }});
```

After doing this for once when I am physically rotating the device the screen is not rotating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean to check the status and revert back. Here is the snippet which I did using switch button.

```
aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
});
```